# visual studio does not copy assembly into gac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, gac

I have a class library and a sharepoint project. I have added a reference to the class library in the sharepoint project and when I click deploy I don't see the class library assembly in the gac. I think this is not normal. can any please let me know how can I solve this issue without resorting to manual deployment? thank you.

Comment: just deploying it does not gac it you have to use / run the gac utility on the machine where you are deploying it to

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to open the package in the package editor, go to Advanced, and add the class library's DLL there. It doesn't happen automatically just from adding an assembly reference to the Sharepoint project.

Comment: how can it be explained that at work it does work without copying it manually? Visual studio does it for me, but on my own computer it does not. Thank you for your quick reply

Comment: I'm also curious to know how it does it automatically. It could be that you've deployed the same class library previously with another Sharepoint solution, or you have some VS plugin that does it for you that you don't have at home... Nothing definite I can think of.

Comment: I think I have almost the same applications and plugins that I have on my own computer and on my own computer I think I have more plugins than at work. I will check tomorrow and see what might cause it.